# Resolution & viewport for devices

Tags: website-design, ux-field

I need some help. I need to do some responsive design, and I have a headache with this resolution (970 px width).

This resolution is odd to me, and when I ask a front end developer to tell me a height or which device uses that resolution, he doesn't know.

Can anyone tell me the height and viewport for this?

I need to know how much content I can display without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to know it by yourself when the resolution is not standard. If you know a little bit of HTML or you can take help of frontend developer you will be able to figure it out with:

**CSS Media Queries:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 970px){
  /* place a class that will change text color to know the limit */
}
```

**Or else:**
Open the URL in Firefox and press `ctrl+shift+M`. The browser will show you a responsive screen where you can enter your own custom resolution and check.

Answer (score 1):

They might be refering to a breakpoint for Responsive layouts.
In [this list of breakpoints](https://material.google.com/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints) you can see that 960px is a good breakpoint between small and medium screens.

In this [Google Material resource (Device metrics)](https://material.io/devices/) you can check devices and their resolution as well as other characteristics.

There is no device with an exact 970px width in that list.

[Here](http://mydevice.io/devices/) is another useful site.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already do some research and did not find any device with that resolution.I think that they do something wrong. I will make then on 960.